# Which filesystem to use for a samba share when all clients use Windows 7?

Tags: windows, filesystems, samba

My NAS runs Linux and currently directly shares its XFS directories. Since I want to use encryption (e.g. TrueCrypt or dm-crypt/LUKS), I have the freedom of filesystem choice for the container. All clients run Windows 7, so which filesystem should I use for the shared container to have the least amount of compatibility issues? The fact that e.g. ext3 doesn't store a file creation date seems to confuse some client tools, but would using ntfs or fat32 actually fix this or is samba3 assuming a Linux filesystem anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by "use encryption"?

Comment: @SvenW Sorry I could have elaborated on that a bit (although it's basically irrelevant): I'm using a TrueCrypt (or maybe dm-crypt) container which encrypts a loopback mounted file. The result is that at the end I have a virtual disk the filesystem of which I can choose freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have this encrypted container on the NAS and want to share the FS inside the container via Samba. In this case, use a Linux FS like ext3/4 or XFS. That's what Samba expects and works best with, as it doesn't even know about this encryption stuff.

Comment: Yes, I want to samba-share the contents, so the encryption was basically too much information, sorry. So would samba still screw up with Windows client attempts to obtain an actual file creation date no matter which FS I chose?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Samba(3) cannot store this attribute at all, regardless of the file system, as this attribute doesn't exist in the Unix environment. I believe Samba4 can store the date in an extended attribute, but am not sure about that.

Comment: For the whole ugly store, read http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/

Comment: I see. So I'll stick with ext3, thanks